# How to start a new activity on Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am attempting Facebook Login Using the new Facebook SDK and the latest Android Studio. It works perfectly. But my issue is that upon success it does not open MainActivity. How do I open a new activity upon verification of Facebook email and password?

Here's my Login Class:

```
    package ///add your own package name;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import apppackage.utils.Constants;
import apppackage.utils.ValidateUserInfo;

import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
            "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
    };
    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* Is there a ConnectionResult resolution in progress? */
    private boolean mIsResolving = false;
    /* Should we automatically resolve ConnectionResults when possible? */
    private boolean mShouldResolve = false;

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    private SignInButton mPlusSignInButton;
    private Button mEmailSignInButton;

    private TextView txt_create, txt_forgot;
    private LoginButton facebookLoginButton;

    ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        initInstances();
    }

    private void initInstances() {
        // Set up the login form.
        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        txt_create = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_create);
        txt_create.setOnClickListener(this);

        txt_forgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_forgot);
        txt_forgot.setOnClickListener(this);

        mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Google+ Login
        mPlusSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.g_sign_in_button);
        mPlusSignInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        mPlusSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .build();

        //Facebook Login
        facebookLoginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.f_sign_in_button);
        facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Callback registration
        facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {

                            }
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error on Login, check your facebook app_id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
            return;
        }

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        ValidateUserInfo validateUserInfo = new ValidateUserInfo();

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !validateUserInfo.isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!validateUserInfo.isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }


    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

        mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.g_sign_in_button:
                onSignInClicked();
                break;
            case R.id.email_sign_in_button:
                attemptLogin();
                break;
            case R.id.txt_create:
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.TAG_EMAIL, email);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.txt_forgot:
                Intent intentForgot = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPassActivity.class);
                intentForgot.putExtra(Constants.TAG_EMAIL, email);
                startActivity(intentForgot);
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void onSignInClicked() {
//        toastLoading.show();
        // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
        // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
        ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "Connecting...", "Atempting to connect", true);
        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mShouldResolve = true;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mShouldResolve = false;
        getProfileInformation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
        // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
        // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d(Constants.TAG_LOGIN, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(Constants.TAG_LOGIN, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mIsResolving = false;
                }
            } else {
                // Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
                // error dialog.
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error on Login, check your google + login method", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            // Show the signed-out UI
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     * */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String birth = currentPerson.getBirthday();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
//                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
//                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
//                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            //new LoadProfileImage().execute(personPhotoUrl);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            try {
                // Simulate network access.
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }

            for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
                String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                    // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                    return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
                }
            }

            // TODO: register the new account here.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run UI based methods on threads other than the main thread. For those cases, use runOnUIThread() method, as in

```
runOnUIThread( new Runnable(){
     startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
     finish();
})
```

Comment: Where do i implement this for the app to work..i am getting errors

Answer (score 0):

> How do I open a new activity upon verification of Facebook email and password?

I see that you have called `registerCallback`. It has three methods:

1. `onSuccess` - This is called when the user successfully logs in.
2. `onCancel` - This gets called when the login is cancelled. For example by closing the facebook login box.
3. `onError`- This gets called when there are errors in login.

You need to start the activity after successfully login through the facebook. So, you need to put the `startActivity` method in the `onSuccess` method of `registerCallback`:

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        // App code
```

The second thing that you don't want to miss when you're using the facebook login is calling the method `onActivityResult`. You have to put this in your LoginActivity.class:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```